# Select only the cell but highlight the entire row in a table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In my table I have set

```
table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
```

so that I can have a user select an individual cell and use ctrl-c to copy/paste the contents of the cell elsewhere. However, I would also like for the entire row to be highlighted (like is done with only `table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true)`). Is there an easy way to accomplish this or does it require a custom renderer for the table?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to select multiple columns/rows or only have one highlight at a time?

Comment: @MadProgrammer only highlight a single row at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want only selected cell to be copied to clipboard.I have done this.This will copy the selected cell content [on Ctrl+C] only to clipboard and at the same time whole row is highlighted as well

I've implemented Copy only you can implement cut and paste if you want.

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class TableTest extends JFrame {
JTable table;

public TableTest() {
    table = new JTable();
    this.add(table);
    //Adding table with four columns and rows
    table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][]{
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String[]{
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
    ));
    //Adding table listener for Copy Ctrl+C
    addTableListener();
}

private void addTableListener() {
    table.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.isControlDown()) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C) {
                    copy();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void cancelEditing() {
    if (table.getCellEditor() != null) {
        table.getCellEditor().cancelCellEditing();
    }
}

public void copy() {
    cancelEditing();//To cancel editing if the cell is in edited mode
    int row = table.getSelectedRow();
    int col = table.getSelectedColumn();
    if (row != -1 && col != -1) {
        Object value = table.getValueAt(row, col);
        value = value != null ? value : "";
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(value.toString());
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TableTest test = new TableTest();
    test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    test.pack();
    test.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    test.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Assuming that you don't use `setCellSelectionEnabled`, then, in my testing, it still allows for multiple columns to be selected (but this might be desired)

Comment: Can you eloborate your problem more.

Comment: After setting the selection mode in the manner you suggested, an entire row is highlighted on selection (which was already the default) but the focus does not go to the single cell that is selected so that a user can use ctrl-c to copy/paste the contents of that cell. Instead, ctrl-c copys the entire row (including awkward white space for breaks between columns)

Comment: @jkeuhlen I've modified the answer check it

Comment: @Madhan I tried that combination after your initial suggestion too. It causes only the selected cell to be highlighted, rather than the entire row.

Comment: So you want to select only one row at a time.not more than that.And you also dont want the user to select individual cells as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82107/discussion-between-madhan-and-jkeuhlen).